# Filter formula: "The requested operation is invalid"

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am starting with PA and I am following several tutorials and the docs. Currently I get this error in my OnStart event of the app:

[image]

> The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: LocalizedTexts
> failed: Expression "locale eq null" is not supported.

The message I get at runtime says that only "eq" or "ne" etc. are allowed. If I change the formula to use those, I also get errors even when I type. Preview works without issues, running the app finally throws this error.
Please be patient with me, but I just don't get it here.

By the way I followed this tutorial for a multi-language app: https://youtu.be/t-yCb70FLwY?t=1391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With(
{
varLanguage: coalesce(….
},

Clearcollect(…)
)

This should get you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, 'With' seems to be the voodoo I needed... Also seems to be universally usable